# Golang how to sort a struct that has a map of string structs

Tags: go

I am working on a project that stores a little bit of analytics data. Everything is working oké but I am just facing one issue where I have to sort the contents of, for example: TotalsPerDay["2022-02-01"] on the amount of clicks.

I cannot figure out how to properly do this. The reason I chose for a map[string]struct{} is that I need the keys as dates and the values as structs so I can, somewhere else in the program, loop through all the records and sum up a total for that specific day.

```
dataModel := types.DataModel{
   Totals: types.DataModelTotals{
      Clicks:           0,
      Impressions:      0,
      Position:         0,
      ClickThroughRate: 0,
      TotalsPerDay:     map[string]types.DataModelTotalsPerDay{},
   },
   Searches:     map[string]types.Searches{},
   Pages:        map[string]types.Pages{},
   Countries:    map[string]types.Countries{},
   Devices:      map[string]types.Devices{},
   SearchFilter: map[string]types.SearchFilter{},
   Dates:        map[string]types.Dates{},
}
```

What TotalsPerDay could look like:

```
TotalsPerDay {
  DataModelTotalsPerDay["2022-02-01"]{ Clicks: 17 },
  DataModelTotalsPerDay["2022-02-01"]{ Clicks: 9 },
  DataModelTotalsPerDay["2022-02-01"]{ Clicks: 82 }
  DataModelTotalsPerDay["2022-02-01"]{ Clicks: 52 }
}
```

What I would like it to be:

```
TotalsPerDay {
  DataModelTotalsPerDay["2022-02-01"]{ Clicks: 82 },
  DataModelTotalsPerDay["2022-02-01"]{ Clicks: 52 },
  DataModelTotalsPerDay["2022-02-01"]{ Clicks: 17 },
  DataModelTotalsPerDay["2022-02-01"]{ Clicks: 9 }
}
```

The reason I have the keys as a date (string) is because in the front-end I need to loop through the dates to display them and this way it was very easy to do.

Hope someone can help me out with this as I have been stuck for this for the past few days.

I tried looking into various sort functions but none got me the result I wanted so far.
I also read somewhere (not sure if this is true) that the elements of a map cannot be sorted? if that is true, how am I supposed to get my data summed up in a way so when send to the front-end they can simply loop over the dates and for each date easily get the amount of clicks and other statistics?

Below is a JSON version of TotalsPerDay.

```
{"2022-08-27 00:00:00 +0000 UTC":{"clicks":6,"impressions":7558,"position":280683.4432563555,"clickThroughRate":280669.4432563555,"totalRrows":5436},"2022-08-28 00:00:00 +0000 UTC":{"clicks":1,"impressions":8061,"position":289043.214145452,"clickThroughRate":288990.8808121187,"totalRrows":5665},"2022-08-29 00:0 0:00 +0000 UTC":{"clicks":8,"impressions":8283,"position":303046.8245871944,"clickThroughRate":302952.8245871944,"totalRrows":5905},"2022-08-30 00:00:00 +0000 UTC":{"clicks":4,"impressions":8447,"position":300142.1673121948,"clickThroughRate":300071.1673121948,"totalRrows":5904},"2022-08-31 00:00:00 +0000 UTC": {"clicks":7,"impressions":8114,"position":285296.87973927736,"clickThroughRate":285158.87973927736,"totalRrows":5648},"2022-09-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC":{"clicks":6,"impressions":8306,"position":297513.4591694122,"clickThroughRate":297337.4591694122,"totalRrows":5932},"2022-09-02 00:00:00 +0000 UTC":{"clicks":4,"impressions":7938,"position":284144.3877642734,"clickThroughRate":284102.3877642734,"totalRrows":5590},"2022-09-03 00:00:00 +0000 UTC":{"clicks":0,"impressions":7024,"position":266604.6929695027,"clickThroughRate":266536.6929695027,"totalRrows":5205}}
```

Comment: Go maps do not maintain order. If you need an order, collect the keys, sort the keys by your custom logic (number of clicks associated with the keys), and when sending the map, iterate over the keys and send the elements in that order. You may also create your own custom map type that implements `json.Marshaler` which does this in it.

Comment: What if I change the map[string]types.DataModelTotalsPerDay{} to a regular []types.DataModelTotalsPerDay{}, can I sort that?

Comment: Yes, of course you can sort slices.

Comment: FYI: to sort slices, golang has the rather aptly named `sort` package